# Stylelint not linting component.module.scss in Next.js

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier, stylelint, scss-lint

I two projects, one with React (v17.0.2) and the other with Next.js (v11.1.0) In both I
have implemented ESlint with Prettier and Stylelint.

My problem is that in React project everything is working smoothly and fine, however in Next.js project, **stylelint is not linting component.modules.scss** files (but other.css files are).

In React, scss files are in ./src/assets/scss/*
in Next.js scss files are in ./styles/*

These are the config files content:

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react", 
    "react-hooks", 
    "jsx-a11y", 
    "only-warn",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 2021,
    "ecmaFeature": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "next"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/jsx-curly-newline": ["off", "consistent"],
    "react/jsx-handler-names": "off",
    "react/display-name": ["off"],
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "off"
  }
}
```

**.prettierrc**

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "parser": "flow",
  "semi": false,
  "useTabs": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "stylelintIntegration": true
}
```

**.stylelintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines",
    "plugins": [
    "stylelint-scss"
  ],
  "rules": {
        "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
    "scss/at-rule-no-unknown": true,
    "indentation": 2,
    "number-leading-zero": null,
        "max-nesting-depth": 10
  }
}
```

Any help please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found what was wrong;

Need to add this in .vscode/settings.json

```
"stylelint.validate": ["css", "scss", ".module.scss"]
```

.module.scss was not considered as .scss, so adding it to the config made everything works